How To Make All Flex Items The Same Length As The One With Longest Text With No Text Wrap
I am trying to make all sibling flex items the same width as the one with the longest text, without making its text wrap. So if an item has the text "First" and another one has much longer text, the two should still have the same width without making the longer one wrap its text. If this is not possible with just CSS and you may have a React solution, I'm all ears. Thanks!
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">First </div>
  <div class="item">Second thing is long </div>
  <div class="item">Third is </div>
  <div class="item">Fourth is even longer and longer </div>
  <div class="item">Fifth </div>
  <div class="item">Sixth </div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto; //it's okay if the items overflow and scroll
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 130px;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red; // the color here is to make it easier to see if all the items are the same width
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 6); //the number 6 here will be dynamic, but it will always be the number of items in the container
}


This picture shows how it's looking right now

Not with flex, but you can do something with grid if you know the maximum number of items you'll have.

I'm  not clear on the requirement - what happens if you need more than 800px to fit everything in? I see you have set no-wrap - but do you mean that on the container? And I assume that the longest text will at least fit into the 800px (?)

White space doesn't allow the text to move in second line and overflow will allow scroll in whichever child text will be larger than its width
     .container {  
width: 800px;  
display: flex;  
background: blue; 
overflow: auto;   
flex-wrap: nowrap;  
height: 130px;
}
    .item {  
margin: 10px;  
background: red;    
display: flex;  
flex-wrap: nowrap; 
flex-basis: calc(100% / 6); 
// add below in css and remove flex-shrink property  
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:auto;
    }


This is close, but it's still the same situation I was having. Each item should not scroll or wrap. So whatever the natural width of the item with the longest text is, all the other items should have the same width. Thanks!

So here is something you are trying to achieve and here is a sample code to help
html code
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">First</div>
  <div class="item">Second thing is long</div>
  <div class="item">Third is</div>
  <div class="item">Fourth is even longer and longer</div>
  <div class="item">Fifth</div>
  <div class="item">Sixth</div>
</div>


css code
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  overflow-x: auto; /* Allow scrolling if needed */
  height: 130px;
}

.item {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text wrapping */
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* Make all items grow equally */
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1 1 0; /* This allows the container to consider the longest item */
  visibility: hidden; /* Prevents the content from showing */
  white-space: nowrap;
}


output image

Just a brief explanation of the css properties i used

flex: 1 1 auto; on .item makes all items grow equally based on the longest one.
white-space: nowrap; ensures that the text inside .item does not wrap.
and the ::before pseudo-element tricks the flex container into considering the natural width of the longest item

the ::before has a flex: 1 1 0 rule, making the container adapt its width based on the longest item, which then forces all items to match the same width.
then this rule visibility: hidden ensures this pseudo-element doesn’t appear visually but still takes part in layout calculations.
